# Ruby NameError problem

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, module

I write simple class with 1 functions in ruby. This functions deleting spaces from string.

My code:

```
module TestString
      class StringUtils    
        #
        # Delete space from string
        #
        def remove_space str
          space = " "
          str.delete space
        end
       end
      end
```

Now i try to write simple test for this function:

```
require 'teststring'

class TestStringUtils < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_remove_space
   assert_equal("Teststring", TestString::StringUtils.new().remove_space("Test string"))
  end
end
```

when i try to run test i get error:

```
  1) Error:
test_remove_space(TestStringUtils):
NameError: uninitialized constant TestStringUtils::Json
    /home/workspace/lib/test.rb:16:in `test_remove_space'
```

Why? Please explain me what's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to `require` the file with your `TestStringUtils` in the file with the test.

Comment: Also unless code sample is incomplete, StringUtils is not inside a module named Json.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i have TestStringUtils code in test.rb, i must put require 'test' in test.rb, i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you, i mixed, class StringUtils in the TestString module.